# Can't extract page numbers from some images in 'non-readable' pdf files

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to extract page numbers from 'non-readable' pdf files after converting them to images using pytesseract

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\DB658WN\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
img = cv2.imread('./Sample2.PNG', 0)

df = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, lang='eng',config='--psm 6', output_type = 'data.frame')
n_boxes = len(df['text'])
for i in range(n_boxes):
    if int(df['conf'][i]) > 10:
        if int(df['top'][i]) > 600:
            if df['text'][i].isdigit():
                print('Page #: ', df['text'][i])
```

So, the code seems to be working for some of the scanned images but it's not working for all of them, please advice how can I fix this

Comment: Do preprocessing before feeding it to the pytesseract. and use oem.

Comment: I did try that but it’s still not working for some images! Is there another approach I can take? Image_to_string or using the image height from image.shape()

Comment: You'll need to provide some images for us to figure out what might be wrong.